# Existing Conditional Formating destroyed after saving the file through python

Tags: python, formatting, conditional-statements

I am using a code in python to open an existing excel file which has conditional formatting in it.
The code opens the file, adds some numbers in it and saves the file with a different name in a different folder.
When i open the new file saved, the conditional formatting exists but not working the same way. The conditional formatting is a Data Bar in which i have set minimum value zero and maximum value 1. The problem is that the minimum and maximum values do not hold any more in the new file as they were set in the initial file. Specifically, for a value of 0 the bar is not completely empty (a short bar shows up) and for a value of 1 the bar is not completely full.

I aam sure that thereason that causes this has nothing to do with the numbers added in the file because i've runed the code without this step and the issue remains.

This is the code i am using:

```
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('Output Predictions Prototype File.xlsx') # Opens the original excel output prediction file
sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Output Predictions') # Chooses the 'Output Prediction' sheet in the file

sheet['C5'] ='Report Date: ' + currentYear + '-' + currentMonth + '-' + currentDay #inserts report date in the format YYYY-MM-DD

Entity_name_and_code = Entity_names[i] + ' - (' + Entity_codes[i] +')' # Creates string with entity name and entity code
sheet['C7'] =Entity_name_and_code

sheet['D9'] = notch_to_rating_class[rating_predictions[i]] # Inserts the predicted rating in cell D9

# Inserts the predicted probabilities
sheet['D12'] = probabilities[i][4]
sheet['D13'] = probabilities[i][3]
sheet['D14'] = probabilities[i][2]
sheet['D15'] = probabilities[i][1]
sheet['D16'] = probabilities[i][0]

sheet['E19'] = 13-NA_counter_for_bank_i     # Inserts the number of variables with availiable data
sheet['E20'] = NA_counter_for_bank_i     # Inserts the number of variables with N/A data


filename='CFS_Prediction_' + Current_Year_Month_Day + '_' + Entity_codes[i] + '.xlsx'    #Stores the name of the file in a string    
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Python Files - Projects\\Output Prediction Files\\'    #File path were we want to save the files in
complete_file_name = file_path + filename     # Complete file path with the file name at the end
xfile.save(complete_file_name)
```

Comment: sounds like a bug report with reproduction steps to openpyxl - why ask where? If just opening /saving your file again reproduces it, it seems to be a issue needed to be fixed by the supporters of openpyxl. you might want to file the bug and provide your xlsx to them

Comment: How do i report it to them ?

Comment: probably:   https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues   - eventually the issue might be reported already